# Remote objects activation doubt

Tags: c#, .net, remoting, activation

If two clients do Activation.GetObject, using the Singleton approach, and the same address, are they going to get the same instance of the class? Or will each client get a different instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their proxies will point to same instance.